Binding expression not working in Azure function SQL Trigger
I have a simple SqlTrigger Azure function. I am trying to set the ConnectionStringSetting property dynamically through code but it's not working and the function is throwing below exception:-

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql: ConnectionStringSetting
'SqlConnectionStringSetting' is missing in your function app settings,
please add the setting with a valid SQL connection string.

I am setting the Environment variable in the Program.cs file:-
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionStringSetting","myCS");

And using the same in trigger like this:-
public async Task Run(
    [SqlTrigger("[dbo].[ToDo]", "%SqlConnectionStringSetting%")]

What's weird is if I just add the setting in my local.settings.json file as Environment variable and not as ConnectionString, it's working. So I am wondering why it's not working when I am setting the same programmatically?

Having looked into the issue, it seems that Azure Functions do not support imperative binding for SQL Trigger functions. That means, that you will always need to have your SQLConnectionString set in your AppSettings in your Azure App Service.
For other types of functions/triggers, you can perform runtime binding by using IBinder or Binder as per Microsoft's documentation here. This documentation also details the list of input and output bindings that support runtime bindings:

If you really need to set the connection string programmatically, the only solution that I can think of, is using the Azure CLI api method:
az functionapp config appsettings set

You could either execute this using your CI/CD pipelines (GitHub Actions, for example), or create another Azure Function that is charged with modifying the function's appsettings...
You can find documentation for the Azure CLI API methods here.
